# Why is pytesseract throwing WinError 6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-tesseract

This is my first time using pytesseract. I'm trying to perform a simple OCR on a small image. The code boils down to:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

test = Image.open(r'C:\test.jpg')
print(image_to_string(test))
```

This throws OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(image_to_string(test))
  File "C:\\pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "C:\\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\\subprocess.py", line 911, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\\subprocess.py", line 1150, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = self._make_inheritable(c2pwrite)
  File "C:\\subprocess.py", line 1182, in _make_inheritable
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

I'm using Python 3.5 on Windows 7.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the real issue but the issue got resolved once I restarted the PC.

Comment: This would be more suited to a comment as it does not directly help "answer" the question

Comment: I don't have right to comment. Will take care if future.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.. So I don't know enough about Python to troubleshoot all the various files, but I did notice for me the issue was due to the subprocess file. Somehow when pytesseract calls subprocess, the script throws an error.

In any case, I got around the problem by skipping pytesseract altogether, and accessing tesseract via subprocess. My code below:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
image_file = r"C:\Temp\test.png"
outlocation = r"C:\Temp\output"
command = ['tesseract', image_file, outlocation]
proc = subprocess.Popen(command,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This is very much a band aid solution, but it did allow me to proceed with the usage of tesseract in python. Hope it helps.

Also, the workaround above assumes you already have tesseract installed. In case you don't, you can grab it from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki